# How to access Landsat bucket from Amazon?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I tried to access amazon Landsat S3 bucket with the following python code

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

access_key = <userid>
secret_key = <pwd>
conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key)

nasaNexBucket = conn.get_bucket("nasanex")

for key in nasaNexBucket.list():
    print key.name
```

and getting this down error. Can anyone help me how to access landsat s3?

> " nasaNexBucket = conn.get_bucket("nasanex")   File
>   "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\connection.py",
>   line 502, in get_bucket
>       return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)   File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\connection.py",
>   line 535, in head_bucket
>       raise err S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden "

Comment: You are not allowed to access the URL according to the 403 Forbidden. Stupid question, but are you passing correct credentials to the server?  Or perhaps, does the server require any special headers or anything, or does it use IP filtering?  I don't know much about the module being used, but those are usual hangups for me in .NET stuff.

Comment: Think you need metadata first see this python code https://github.com/landsat-pds/landsat_ingestor (recently updated)